# JQuery - Using Nested .when functions

Tags: jquery

If I'm not using the language correctly, please teach me!! :)

I have a when statement that works as expected, which is to say that the deferred code waits until getLocInfo has returned it's promise before executing:

```
var schoolID_alt;
var schoolLevel;

$.when(getLocInfo()).then(function() {
    if (schoolLevel == '03') {
        //Opportunities & Access
        getAPResults();

        //CCR
        getCCRCareerReady();
        getCCRCollegeReady();
        getCCRReady();
    }
    else {  //This is not a high school so hide the CCR section!!
        $('.sl03').hide();
    }
})

function getLocInfo() {
    var parm = { schoolID_alt: schoolID_alt };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        url: "WebServices/myEquity.asmx/getSchoolInfo",
        data: JSON.stringify(parm),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            si = response.d;

            $('#rptTitle').html(si.locationName + '<br/>School Profile');
            $('#subTtl').html('Data Key: ' + si.locationName + ' (' + si.schoolLevelName + ')');

            return schoolLevel = si.schoolLevel;
        }
    })
}
```

However, if I wrap this inside of a another when function...the new when function works as expected, but the code inside the now-internal 'when' that previously worked now fires immediately instead of waiting for getLocInfo() to return its promise...can somebody please help explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
$.when(schoolID_alt = getUrlParameter('schoolID_alt')).then(function () {
    $.when(getLocInfo()).then(function() {
        if (schoolLevel == '03') {
            //Opportunities & Access
            getAPResults();

            //CCR
            getCCRCareerReady();
            getCCRCollegeReady();
            getCCRReady();
        }
        else {  //This is not a high school so hide the CCR section!!
            $('.sl03').hide();
        }
    })
})

function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getUrlParameter(sParam) is not asynchronous why are you using a promise?

Comment: $.when expects you to supply a Promise object to it, but "getLocInfo()" doesn't return a promise. Try writing `return $.ajax({`...etc inside that function. It executes one, but it doesn't return it. And also `return schoolLevel = si.schoolLevel;`; inside the "success" is meaningless - 1) it returns the result of an assignment statement, which isn't much use, and 2) there's nowhere for it to return to anyway - it's an async callback...the variable you return doesn't go anywhere (or at least, nowhere that you can make use of it).

Comment: And yeah as madalin points out, feeding the result of getUrlParameter() to a $.when call also makes no sense because it's not async and doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: Thanks...I'm learning JQuery as I go and obviously have a long ways to go.  After reading your feedback and I went back and studied some more.  I have a better understanding, I think, for how deferreds work and asynchronous functions...thanks again for the nudge in the right direction!